Gradlew error when running doctor in React Native
I keep getting this error on react native doctor:
✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
✖ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
i keep getting this error and i dont know why. I even installed gradle to my pc.

Are you sure you're on the correct directory ?
This error means there is no Gradle wrapper in the project/directory you're in.
Make sure your project has a gradlew file in it.
